# How can I get image value and implement on any another div in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actually I have multiple images so now I need to display clicked image on another box how can I do that in react?

My Code:-

```js
    const imageClick = () =>{
      console.log(this.state.value);
    }


 <img src="images/1.png" onClick={()=>imageClick()} />
 <img src="images/2.png" onClick={()=>imageClick()} />
 <img src="images/3.png" onClick={()=>imageClick()} />
 <img src="images/4.png" onClick={()=>imageClick()} />

 <div className="newDiv"></div>
```

Not able to understand what is better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
const imageClick = (selectedImg) =>{
  this.setState({ selectedImg }) // Save the selected image in this.state
}

<img src="images/1.png" onClick={()=>imageClick(1)} />
<img src="images/2.png" onClick={()=>imageClick(2)} />
<img src="images/3.png" onClick={()=>imageClick(3)} />
<img src="images/4.png" onClick={()=>imageClick(4)} />

<div className="newDiv">
  <img src={`images/${this.state.selectedImg}.png`} /> // Get the selected image from this.state
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the component where you're trying to run this?

Comment: Its working now... Thank you !, Can you explain what is the use of $ in this code? actually not bale to understand...

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. The $ is for using expressions inside template literals [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). You could also get the same outcome with src={"images/"+this.state.selectedImg+".png"}, I just prefer using template literals.